# How do I delete lots ( >10,000) of files on Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox

The Desktop client is freezing up on me, and the web interface says "use the Desktop client" if you try to delete more than just a few thousand at once.

Comment: I would contact Dropbox support in order to determine the best method.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the down vote. Please be courteous, and leave a comment saying what is wrong with the question. It's a genuine question!

Comment: Dropboxes help even says to contact support. I did so. After 3 working days, I got a message back telling me to read the help.

Comment: Oh yes, and I'm answering my own question below as this took me *ages* to work out how to get round, and I want to help people in future. Would love a better answer!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm not entirely sure this is *on topic* here. I don't see any close votes yet, but this seems to be more of a webapps issue..

Comment: What operating system are you using? Have you tried from the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Desktop client again - it's the best way with a user interface.

Otherwise, use the "search" feature in the web interface. This can get you a list of 100 files at a time. You can then click the first and shift click the last to select them, and right click and choose "delete". This lets you delete 100 at a time.

If you're a programmer, you can automate this with the REST API. Using whatever API bindings you can find, call the "search" feature repeatedly (e.g. with every letter A-Z) to get the lists of files one hundred at a time. For each call the "rm" API call to individual delete it.

It's possible there's a command line tool a power user could use to do this, but I haven't found it specifically - I just coded using the API.

Comment: do you have the client running while deleting? Tried with the client exited?